# Oracle 19c Standard Edition RPM installation

Tags: oracle, oracle-18c, oracle-19c

I'm wondering if it's possible to install Oracle Standard Edition from RPM, not Enterprise Edition. It's possible to choose edition when you do 'runInstaller', is it possible to set some parameter during rpm installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Restrictions and Guidelines for RPM-Based Installations](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ladbi/restrictions-for-rpm-based-installations.html#GUID-22C1C4C1-49BE-4664-9A73-E96F70665633)

- Patching Oracle Database software using RPMs is not supported. Please    use the OPatch utility and follow the regular patching process to    apply Oracle Database patches.
- **An RPM-based Oracle Database    installation is not available for Standard Edition 2.**
- RPM-based    database upgrades using rpm -Uvh is not supported. For Oracle    Database upgrades, follow the regular upgrade process.
- An RPM-based    installation supports the installation of multiple Oracle Database    software versions into different Oracle homes on the same machine.

Comment: thank you! Again!